# Obtaining historical values for a stock

Tags: stocks, historical-data

Is there any way, given a stock symbol, to obtain historical data for it? 
For example, if I want to calculate the 200 day average for a quote I would need the closing price for a add stock for the last 200 days.  How can I obtain that?

Comment: Try Yahoo finance, they actually let you graph a moving average if you wish, no math or spreadsheet required.

Comment: In fact most charting software already does this for you, no need to calculate it. There is no need to try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: JoeTaxpayer but can I download the data? Or I can only chart online?

Comment: Victor as I mentioned to JoeTaxpayer... I know most charting software does it for me but how can I grab hold of the data itself?

Comment: There are a lot of charting packages that provide historical data which you usually have to pay for.

Comment: OK, I just noticed I can get the data from Yahoo in Historical Prices. Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, as you saw, Yahoo offers a download if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this link to get [historical prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL+Historical+Prices)